# CUDA : Shared memory alignement in documentation

Tags: c++, cuda

We can see on the [official Nvidia website](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/) that to use multiple arrays of shared memory of unknow size, we can use that code in the kernel:

```cpp
__global__ void myKernel() {
  extern __shared__ int s[];
  int *integerData = s;                        // nI ints
  float *floatData = (float*)&integerData[nI]; // nF floats
  char *charData = (char*)&floatData[nF];      // nC chars
}

// Kernel launch
myKernel<<<gridSize, blockSize, nI*sizeof(int)+nF*sizeof(float)+nC*sizeof(char)>>>(...);
```

However, we know that the memory should also be aligned. Isn't this code undefined behaviour if for example `sizeof(float) == 8` and `sizeof(int) == 4` ? This may be a convoluted size, but the problem is more apparent if we just put the char on top:

```
__global__ void myKernel() {
  extern __shared__ char s[];
  char *charData = s;      // nC chars
  int *integerData = (int*)&s[nC];             // nI ints
  float *floatData = (float*)&integerData[nI]; // nF floats
}
```

If `nC` is not multiple of `sizeof(int)`, the pointers are misaligned.
So my question is, does this work for this specific example or should I worry about alignment ? And if yes, what is the common pattern or how to manage that in code ?

Comment: @talonmies compute-sanitizer reports misaligned memory accesses with your example code

Comment: @AbatorAbetor: That's interesting, I ran a full example on the Tegra I have at hand and it worked, unless I made a mistake somewhere

Comment: `sizeof(float) == 4`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to worry about alignment.

The easiest way to get around this is to sort arrays by alignment from largest to smallest, meaning double + long long -> float + int -> …

Since all integral types have sizes and alignments that are powers of 2, you won't waste any space when you pack your arrays like that. Extra care needs to be taken around platform-specific types like size_t or wchar_t. Same goes with vector types. float3 has lower alignment than float2.

In normal C++ code, we could use `std::align` to compute our pointers. But that doesn't work with CUDA, so we roll our own version if we need a generic solution.

```
#include <cstdint>

/**
 * in normal code we could use std::align but that doesn't work with CUDA
 *
 * Behavior is undefined if alignment is not a power of 2
 * (same as everywhere else)
 *
 * \tparam T array element type
 * \param n_elements number of array entries
 * \param ptr in-out parameter. On entry, points at first usable location.
 *     On exit, will point at first location after the end of the array
 * \param space if not null, the used space (including padding for alignment)
 *    will be added to the value currently stored in here
 * \return properly aligned pointer to beginning of array
 */
template<class T>
__host__ __device__
T* align_array(std::size_t n_elements, void*& ptr,
      std::size_t* space=nullptr) noexcept
{
    const std::size_t alignment = alignof(T);
    const std::uintptr_t intptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr);
    const std::uintptr_t aligned = (intptr + alignment - 1) & -alignment;
    const std::uintptr_t end = aligned + n_elements * sizeof(T);
    if(space)
        *space += static_cast<std::size_t>(end - intptr);
    ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(end);
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(aligned);
}

__global__ void myKernel(int nI, int nF, int nC)
{
  extern __shared__ char s[];
  void* sptr = s;
  volatile char* charData = align_array<char>(nC, sptr);
  volatile int* integerData = align_array<int>(nI, sptr);
  volatile float* floatData = align_array<float>(nF, sptr);
  floatData[0] = charData[0] + integerData[0];
}

void callKernel(int nI, int nF, int nC)
{
  std::size_t shared_size = 0;
  void* sptr = nullptr;
  align_array<char>(nC, sptr, &shared_size);
  align_array<int>(nI, sptr, &shared_size);
  align_array<float>(nF, sptr, &shared_size);
  myKernel<<<gridsize, blocksize, sharedsize>>>(nI, nF, nC);
}
```

Comment: @talonmies shared memory access needs to be aligned, too, right? See e.g. here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/misalignment-of-shared-memory/28039 The godbolt links shows that the int access is offset by 9 byte. That's not aligned

Comment: @talonmies I'd like to see a reference for that claim. Seeing how shared memory bank size and bank conflicts are still a thing, I don't see how misaligned accesses can be as effective as aligned accesses, even if they are supported.

Comment: You are completely right and I am completely wrong in this case. Knowing that the newer compiler versions have really thorough range and alignment checking for memory and seeing that the compiler emitted code, I hacked a couple of test cases (containing an error) ran them, saw them pass, and convinced myself I was right. My apologies.

Comment: There is some information scattered in the documentation. for example PTX ISA 6.4.1 states `The address must be naturally aligned to a multiple of the access size. If an address is not properly aligned, the resulting behavior is undefined. For example, among other things, the access may proceed by silently masking off low-order address bits to achieve proper rounding, or the instruction may fault.`

Comment: And programming guide B.2.3 `Note that pointers need to be aligned to the type they point to,`

Comment: What if i want to store a `struct` ? How to choose the ordering on a cross-platform program where types may be of different size ?

Comment: @rafoo a struct inherits the maximum alignment of any contained type and its sizeof() will always be a multiple of the alignment. So it isn't too hard to do it manually in most cases. I updated the answer with a template to help with that stuff. Test with caution, may still be buggy.

Comment: Isn't a simple possibility to align every part of the array that belongs to a different primitive to 256 bits ? (The maximum alignment IIRC)

Comment: @rafoo: Sure, but you don't want to waste space in shared memory, do you? Besides, the operation to align the pointer is basically the same as in the template, so you don't really save a lot.