# Cuda misaligned address for a reused shared block memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

My kernel allocated a shared memory for data storage, but bug reports if I change the size of the shared memory, see codes attached.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define cucheck_dev(call)                                   \
{                                                           \
  cudaError_t cucheck_err = (call);                         \
  if(cucheck_err != cudaSuccess) {                          \
    const char *err_str = cudaGetErrorString(cucheck_err);  \
    printf("%s (%d): %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, err_str);   \
    assert(0);                                              \
  }                                                         \
}

__global__ void kernel(int datanum)
{
    extern __shared__ int sh[];

    // assign data for data 1
    float2* data_ptr1((float2*)sh);
    for (int thid = threadIdx.x; thid < datanum; thid += blockDim.x)
    {
      data_ptr1[thid] = make_float2(0., 0.);
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // assign data for data 2
    
    size_t shOffset = (sizeof(float2)/sizeof(int)*(datanum));

    if(threadIdx.x == 0) printf("Offset: %d\n", (int)(shOffset));
    __syncthreads();

    float4 *data_ptr2((float4*)&sh[shOffset]);
    for (int thid = threadIdx.x; thid < datanum; thid += blockDim.x)
    {
        data_ptr2[thid] = make_float4(0., 0., 0., 0.);
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

int main()
{
    int datanum = 21;     // bug reports for datanum = 21, but everthing works fine for datanum = 20
    int blocknum = 1;
    int threadperblock = 128;
    int preallocated = 768;

    size_t shmem = datanum*sizeof(float2) + preallocated*sizeof(int);

    printf("Allocated Shared memory byte: %d  Nums: %d\n", (int)shmem, (int)(shmem/sizeof(int)));

    kernel<<<blocknum, threadperblock, shmem>>>(datanum);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cucheck_dev(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

- OS: Ubuntu 18.02
- Cuda: 10.1
- Device: RTX 2060
- g++: 7.5.0

As shown, the shared memory included two regions, one for fixed data, type as `float2`.

The other region may save different types as `int` or `float4`, offset from the shared memory entry.

When I set `datanum` to 20, codes work fine.

But when `datanum` is changed to 21, the code reports a misaligned address.

I greatly appreciate any reply or suggestions.

Thank you!

Some information provided by `cuda-memcheck` is posted here for a reference:

```
========= Invalid __shared__ write of size 16
=========     at 0x00000280 in kernel(int)
=========     by thread (20,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x000001e8 is misaligned
=========     Device Frame:kernel(int) (kernel(int) : 0x280)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x34e) [0x2efabe]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x13de9]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x13e77]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x4a1c5]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6f32]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6df5]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6e2e]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6c14]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x69fa]
=========
========= Invalid __shared__ write of size 16
=========     at 0x00000280 in kernel(int)
=========     by thread (19,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x000001d8 is misaligned
=========     Device Frame:kernel(int) (kernel(int) : 0x280)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x34e) [0x2efabe]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x13de9]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x13e77]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x4a1c5]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6f32]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6df5]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6e2e]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6c14]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x69fa]
=========
========= Invalid __shared__ write of size 16
=========     at 0x00000280 in kernel(int)
=========     by thread (18,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x000001c8 is misaligned
=========     Device Frame:kernel(int) (kernel(int) : 0x280)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x34e) [0x2efabe]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x13de9]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x13e77]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x4a1c5]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6f32]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6df5]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6e2e]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6c14]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x69fa]
=========
========= Invalid __shared__ write of size 16
=========     at 0x00000280 in kernel(int)
=========     by thread (17,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x000001b8 is misaligned
=========     Device Frame:kernel(int) (kernel(int) : 0x280)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x34e) [0x2efabe]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x13de9]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x13e77]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x4a1c5]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6f32]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6df5]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6e2e]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x6c14]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x69fa]
```

Comment: I try to access the data by the stride of float2, though data is stored in a int array.

Comment: I do not know too much about the array alignment for either int or float2. I just wonder if I can save different types of data (int,float2,float4) within an int array in a flexible way (just try to). Then I can do some operation on these data by different type of pointer, e.g., cast int ptr to a float2 or float4 ptr.

Comment: I would suggest reading the CUDA documentation regarding alignment requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the alignment for `float4` is higher than that for `float2`. Therefore the lines

```
size_t shOffset = (sizeof(float2)/sizeof(int)*(datanum));
float4 *data_ptr2((float4*)&sh[shOffset]);
```

do not guarantee appropriate alignment for data_ptr2 unless datanum is an even number.

I wrote some code for this issue here: [CUDA : Shared memory alignement in documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70765553/cuda-shared-memory-alignement-in-documentation/70766925#70766925)

The easiest fix is to just swap `data_ptr1` and `data_ptr2`. Use the front of the memory for the type with the larger alignment

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Does the higher alignment means that the accessible of float4 (or take the address of float4) is a offset compared to the whole shared entry point instead of the end of float2, am I right? For example, the end of float2 (data1) is 160, if datanum == 20, which means that 10 time of float4 (16 byte on my PC). But if datanum changed to 21, the end of data1 is 168, which is not a integer time of float4, thus misalignment.

Comment: @Mangoccc Yes, the start of the float4 array would be offset from the end of the float2 array, basically wasting 2 floats worth of space. That's why reversing the order of arrays is better. Go from largest to smallest alignment and you never waste space

Comment: Thank you very much! This problem has been solved now!